# Printing iframe shows only a small viewport

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, printing, height

I'm using an `iframe` to prevent the CSS of user-provided content (converted .doc files) from bleeding out of an AJAX panel in my single-page application. It's the last item displayed, usually about 5 pages following 1 page.

It works visually in the screen application, where I have a parent-relative height and width to leverage, but I realized I couldn't actually get the iframe to print its entire contents with `@media print` declarations.

I've seen about 5 related questions answered 'not possible', but I'm more flexible than those askers. I'm willing to:

- use javascript if it can format the print view without affecting the screen view. can you point me to an example?
- I currently directly insert the iframe's html, so I also have a lot of control over its content.
- to print the parent and `iframe` contents separately, if they'll queue seamlessly in major browsers' print managers - especially if there's a way to handle browser print events in this case?
- as a last resort, I will probably print ONLY the `iframe` content, using the following. still would like to handle print events if it's possible cross-browser.

javascript:

```
window.frames["OverlayDis"].focus();
window.frames["OverlayDis"].print();
```